# Iplanet Web Server Dynamic Directory Access

Tags: web-config, iplanet

Hi I'm new to Iplanet web server.
If the access url is ***abc.co.sg/XYZ*** -> would to show ***abc.co.sg/XYZ/index.html*** 
I can do static directory access in **obj.conf**

```
 <Object name="xxx" ppath="/abcd/card/apply">
      NameTrans fn="rewrite"
      root="/app/iplanetweb/docs/abcd/card/apply"
      path="/index.html"
 </Object>
```

What I want is to make the ppath="***Dynamic folder***"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding this rule in default object of obj.conf, is can redirect to index page.
Thank you

```
<If $uri =~ '^/([a-zA-Z0-9+-]+)$'>
    NameTrans fn="redirect" url="$uri/index.html"
</If>
```